# how can I valid where_in empty

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to valid empty where_in in codeigniter, but when I dont have any item on my array i get an error like

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 3

```
SELECT `code`, `description`, `purchase_price`, `sale_price`, `wholesale_price`, `min_stock`, `stock`, `max_stock`, `provider_id` FROM `storelte_products` WHERE `id` IN()
```

how could I valid that error on codeigniter when it's empty?

my code looks like this

controller

```
$this->session->carrito = $this->sale->checar_existe_carrito();
        $array = $this->sale->get_all_cart($this->session->carrito);
        $product_id = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
             $product_id[] = $value['id'];
        }
        print_r($this->products->get_product_id($product_id));
```

model

```
  public function get_product_id($id) {
        $this->db->select('code,description,purchase_price,sale_price,wholesale_price,min_stock,stock,max_stock,provider_id');
        $this->db->from('storelte_products');
        $this->db->where_in('id', $id);
        $response = $this->db->get();
        return $response ? $response->row() : false;
    }
```

Comment: yes I did, it solved my problem..

Comment: what solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

just check if it is empty before executing the query:

```
public function get_product_id($id) {
    if(empty($id))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $this->db->select('code,description,purchase_price,sale_price,wholesale_price,min_stock,stock,max_stock,provider_id');
    $this->db->from('storelte_products');
    $this->db->where_in('id', $id);
    $response = $this->db->get();
    return $response ? $response->row() : false;
}
```